# Spring Security which authorities? SecurityContextHolder's authentication authorities vs Principal's authorities

Tags: java, spring-security, authorization, principal

I'm using Spring Security to provide authentication and authorization to my webapp.

I use the standard method `UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;` to login with a `DaoAuthenticationProvider`.

Once successfully logged in, I can access the user's authorities in two different ways:

1# `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`

2# `((UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getAuthorities()`

They are supposed to be the same, as the Authentication instance authority list is constructed from the UserDetails' user.getAuthorities(), but they are in fact 2 different Collection instances. The principal's one is an UnmodifiableSet, the one in the Authentication instance is an UnmodifiableRandomAccessList.
2 different Collection instances that contain the same list of authority.

This struck me when trying to find a solution to dynamically add an authority to the currently authenticated Principal. It's not a good thing and the security layer should not allow me to do so, but still that's what I need.

A solution I found acceptable was to programmatically login with the currently authenticated user with 
`new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getPrincipal(), authentication.getCredentials(), dbAuthsSet);`

`authentication` being the current authentication instance and `dbAuthSet` the current list of authorities + the one I need to add.

And this works fine. The only odd thing now is that

1# `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`

2# `((UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getAuthorities()`

don't return the same list of authorities anymore.

If I check authorities against the Authentication's list in my application, I'm good, and this is perfectly justified thing to do. But if I check against the Principal's list, I'm faced with the inconsistency.

What do you think? Is it a problem that should be addressed in Spring's Security 3.2?

Do you find it reasonable to programmatically login with `new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken()` to achieve my goal of giving an additional authority to the currently authenticated user for the session?

Would it be a good case to use Spring's [Run-As Authentication Replacement](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/runas.html) feature?
Could anyone share experience on this ?

Comment: I think that the obvious question is - What are you trying to achieve? What is your use-case?

Comment: The business level use-case is for an admin to be able to impersonate a user.
My solution is to dynamically give it the necessary authority after it selects the user to impersonate. It's then seen as a user by the system and can perform user's action.

Comment: Check http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.html

Comment: Very good piece of advice, it's barely mentioned in the Spring 3.1 documentation, I'm glad you pointed it to me. Thank you so much!